Foundations/ footings
Hi I have engaged a builder to pour the foundation for a shed/ man cave. I’ve asked for it to be 600mm deep, I’ve returned home to find that they have poured it at around 400mm and the rebar level markers are exposed by 200mm!
The question here is can another level be put onto the existing pour after they have left it for the weekend?

Is the 600mm a requirement of local regulations for the size of the shed?  Contractor should do as you say, but might be saving you some money if not required.

600 to save on the brick and block up to DPC , at the end of the day I paid for 600mm not 400mm said he’s back Tuesday as they run out of materials!

Curious , what is DPC?     I'd never use that guy again. His planning is unbelievably poor.

Damp proof course

It will depend on the inspector if any.  They probably will not like a second pour if 600mm is required by regulations.  If 400 is what is required then a second pour on top should not hurt.
